# i'm get this error, i don't know what to do, "TypeError: render is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, function, typeerror, render

okay, so i'm new to the react world, and i was learning about the react useContext, i followed exactly what a tutorial on youtube did,  i'm trying to build a little project, i tried following his steps and then i hit an error while trying to use the state i literally want it to be accessible accross my app components, inside my app i've created various componenents and also various responsibility that combines all the reusuable components and do a specific task with it. i'm now trying to access my context from my `GETCLICKEDIMAGES` file, below are my steps

```
StateContext.jsx file

    import React, { useState, createContext  } from "react";

export const StateContext = createContext();

export const StateProvider=(props)=> {
  //all the components in this app will share this state.
  const [names, setNames] = useState([{ name: "Zucci Daniel! its working" }]);

  return (
    <StateContext.Provider value={"helo"}>{props.children}</StateContext.Provider>
  );
}



App.js

    import React, { Component } from "react";
import BigWrapper from "./justComponents/BigWrapper/BigWrapper";
import NavBar from "./justComponents/NavBar/NavBar";
import MainContainer from "./justComponents/MainContainer/MainContainer";
//below are the various responsibilities component
import SEARCHANDDISPLAY from "./Responsibilities/SEARCHANDDISPLAY/SEARCHANDDISPLAY";
import { GETCLICKEDIMAGES } from "./Responsibilities/GETCLICKEDIMAGES/GETCLICKEDIMAGES";

import { StateContext } from "./StateContext/StateContext";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <StateContext>
        <BigWrapper>
          <NavBar />

          <MainContainer>
            <SEARCHANDDISPLAY />
            <GETCLICKEDIMAGES />
          </MainContainer>
        </BigWrapper>
      </StateContext>
    );
  }
}

export default App;


GETCLICKEDIMAGE.jsx 

    import React,{useContext} from "react";
import ClickedImageHolderDiv from "../../justComponents/ClickedImageHolderDiv/ClickedImageHolderDiv";
import Figure from "../../justComponents/Figure/Figure";
//you wanna use the stateContext right? import the context here as so;
import { StateContext } from "../../StateContext/StateContext";
//this is responsible for getting the clicked images and displaying them in full details

/**
 a DIV to hold the FIGURE 
 */
export const GETCLICKEDIMAGES=()=> {

  const value =useContext(StateContext);



  return (
    <ClickedImageHolderDiv>
      <h2>{value}</h2>
      <Figure useThisStyle={{ height: "100%" }} />
    </ClickedImageHolderDiv>
  );
}
```

i don't know if i'm missing something, or something's changed, pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Import `StateProvider` in your app.js instead of `stateContext`